# https data storage/retrieval across domains

Tags: php, mysql, database, https

A client of mine owns 2 dedicated servers - both running php 4.3.
One server (the main) has lots of applications with online payments. He has install SSL key in one subdomain to run the payment procedures. 
So we have www.example-one.com and https://secure.example-one.com, both sharing the same databases.

Now, on his other server (www.example-two.com), he wants to upgrade to latest php/mysql.
He wants to install another ssl there (https://secure.example-two.com), and he wants to transfer all applications from first secure domain, to the new one.

Is there a way to share the databases in the second server? So php scripts can still work and store/retrieve data in the database in first server (www.example-one.com)?

**EDIT:** the two servers (example-one and example-two are running in different IPs)

Comment: I would first consider duplicating the entire system as it is now to the second server. Ensure everything is working and then copy the 'current' database across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It all depends on your physical infrastructure, but if the servers running example-one and example-two can "see" each other across the network - ideally, a non-public network running inside your hosting facility, or a well-secured VPN across the internet - you can connect the PHP apps running on www.example-two.com and secure.example-two.com to the MySQL database on example-one.com by setting the connection string to point at whatever its hostname or IP address is.

You should NOT run this connection over the public internet or any benefit of using SSL on the web application is wiped out.

Comment: So it is actual possible, and depends on how the server admin configures the 2 servers. Good to know. Time to contact the server support team :)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that DB is MySQL, then sure, you can make it listen on a public IP address, restrict access to example-two, and point PHP scripts of example-two to the database of example-one.

Another option is to make a master-master replication between those 2 servers, that would require installing 2nd instance of MySQL on example-two and some careful consideration as to whether application using it won't break (read: auto_increment increment).

[Some instructions on MySQL master-master replication](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication)

Answer (score 1):

you can access every database you like if they are proper configured.

securest way is to have a own backend lan for this.

if you cant you could open mysql on the public ip adress (and filter via iptables to allow only example-two access) add an user to mysql with the proper rights and you are done. (its more a problem of securing the exposed mysql then the actual configuration of mysql is)